# Canvas View Custom constructor doesn't call onDraw

Tags: android, canvas, view, constructor

I have a frame layout with a CanvasView with my "game board", then I have two objects of this class, so them draw different things and, when I call invalidate, it only invalidates the specific object.

The problem is, when I create a new object of canvasView with my default constructor, it never calls onDraw.

```
public Player(View v,int num){
        figura = (CanvasView) v;
```

this way it calls ondraw but if I do

```
figura = new CanvasView("this context", atributes null, something else)
```

it doesn't call onDraw with my default constructor, why? even if I do: setWillNotDraw(false)

Answer (score 0):

Because it isn't on screen.  If it isn't on screen, there's no reason to draw, so onDraw is never called.  You need it to be added to your layout somewhere so it shows up for it to draw.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: it doesn't work even if I do
View v = find ...byid
 new CanvasView(v.getContext(), null, something else)

it's on like that "null" should be something but idk what because when I do figura = (CanvasView) v;
it fills the constructor with v context and some attributes (canvas constructor:(Context con, AttributeSet attr)